# React native and React router native v6

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router

I have: `react-router-native: 6.2.1`.

I have an components:
App.js:

```
const App = () => (
  <NativeRouter>
    <RoutesView />
  </NativeRouter>
)
```

RoutesView.js:

```
const RoutesView = () => (
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Menu />}>
      <Route path="/add" element={<AddPurchases />} />
    </Route>
  </Routes>
)
```

and Menu.js:

```
const Menu = () => (
  <View>
    <Text>Welcome!</Text>
    <Link to="/profile">Visit your profile</Link>
  </View>
)
```

React return me error:

> React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child.

When I remove `<Link to="/profile">Visit your profile</Link>` application work corretly. Why I can't using `<Link />` inside `<Route />`?
How I can fix it?

Comment: Why in RoutesView are you making  a Route inside of another Route?

Comment: @RhettHarrison I'm using this [docs](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#routes-and-route). It's wrong?

Comment: @RhettHarrison That is how you build nested routes and UI.

Comment: What component is being blamed for this error? You're not using a `Link` inside a `Route`, you are using a `Link` inside a `View`. Is the `View` saying it takes only a single child element?

Comment: @DrewReese I don't know if it's `View` fault. But now I Change `Menu` component to: `const Menu = () => <Link to="/profile">Visit your profile</Link>` and I removed `<Route path="/" element={<Menu />}>` from `RoutesView` and I moved `Menu` to App, but still I have this error

Comment: Can you create a *running* [Expo snack](https://expo.dev/) of your code that reproduces the issue we can inspect and debug live?

Comment: @DrewReese Sorry, I don't know how I can share link to Expo snac, but it is my [repo](https://github.com/major697/shopping) branch: `animated-info`

Comment: You can just create an account, if you don't already have one, click create "+ new snack", copy the minimal code to reproduce the issue into it, and share the link.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
export const Menu = () => (
    <View>
      <div className="wrapper">
        <Text>Welcome!</Text>
        <Link to="/profile">Visit your profile</Link>
      </div>
    </View>
);
```

I'm not sure what the View does but I know React like to only return a single element so I wrapped it in a single div element

Comment: It's not working. Still I have this same error

Comment: What component is the error showing up on? @michal

Comment: `View` ***is*** a single element and already wraps what is returned.

Answer (score 1):

```
const Menu = () => (
  <View>
    <Text>Welcome!</Text>
    <Link to="/profile">
       <View>
         <Text>Visit your profile</Text>
       </View>
   </Link>
  </View>
)
```

Wrap the Plain text with view and a text tag it should work

more info found on the issue [link](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/8351#issuecomment-973040561)